# Android AudioManager Event Listener?

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
    Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");
    break;
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
    Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");
    break;
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
    Log.i("MyApp","Normal mode");
    break;
}
```

Using the above code, I can successfully find the various AudioManager RINGER_MODE* types, however I can't seem to find an EventListener that catches when the state has changed. The application I am writing runs in the background, so I'd like to know the the most timely fashion of checking the state of the AudioManager.RINGER_MODE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in your code that listens for the [RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION) intent. This will let you know that the state has changed. Once you receive the intent, you can call getRingerMode() to find out what the current state is.

Answer (score 0):

did you try listening for AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION?